# Wrapping text around a responsive video in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a `<p>` that I need to wrap around a responsive embedded video on my site.

Before I knew my client wanted to have a large amount of `<p>` content, I simply made two columns.

```
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-6 ">

        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">  

            <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $this->page->getPageYouTubeId() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

        </div>                      

      </div>

      <div class="col-md-6 ">

        <h1 class="big-title"><?= $this->page->getPageHeadline()  ?></h1>

        <div class="blog-title">
            <p><?= $this->page->getPageContent() ?></p> 
        </div> 

        <a class="btn btn-default scrollto" href="#content"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> Check Out The Properties!</a>

      </div>

    </div>
```

I know a need to use a `float: left` in someway, but I have tried various things and none of them are working ie...

```
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-12 ">
        <div class="pull-left">
          <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">  

            <iframe src="//www.youtube.com/embed/<?= $this->page->getPageYouTubeId() ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

          </div>
       </div>                      

        <h1 class="big-title"><?= $this->page->getPageHeadline()  ?></h1>

        <div class="blog-title">
            <p><?= $this->page->getPageContent() ?></p> 
        </div> 

        <a class="btn btn-default scrollto" href="#content"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> Check Out The Properties!</a>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
```

I am a backend dev so this stuff isn't my strong suit.

http://webwarephpdevelopment.com:8080/fl/West-Palm-Beach

Comment: not quiet understand where you need your text? inside `<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9"> ` ? in your site there is no text showing next to video.

Comment: yes...since I wasn't getting any answers i have been trying to get to work my self.  what I need is for the text to simply wrap around the video div, and to be honest I'm not sure why my "attempt" code isn't working.